# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo "my apps is force close."

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio-2.2

how to resolve this error, I've tried but have not succeeded, my application has appeared on the screen, but when clicking the "lihatPeta" my apps is force close.

**this is error :**

> 11-24 12:47:01.497 29262-29262/com.example.arf_amella.pariwisatacirebon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                             Process: com.example.arf_amella.pariwisatacirebon, PID: 29262
>                                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arf_amella.pariwisatacirebon/com.example.arf_amella.pariwisatacirebon.Maps_Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>                                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:720)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:331)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2018)
>                                                                                                 at com.example.arf_amella.pariwisatacirebon.Maps_Activity.onCreate(Maps_Activity.java:20)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The API key can only be specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml
>                                                                                                 at maps.y.k.b(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at maps.v.c.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at xu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:62)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
>                                                                                                 at rui.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:179)
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:99)
>                                                                                                 at ruh.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:62)
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzH(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzIL(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1181)
>                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2419)
>                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
>                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
>                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
>                                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:77)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
>                                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:331) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2018) 
>                                                                                                 at com.example.arf_amella.pariwisatacirebon.Maps_Activity.onCreate(Maps_Activity.java:20) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XkMv.jpg)

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button tombolDaftar, tombolPeta;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tombolDaftar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tombolPeta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
}

public void lihatDaftar1 (View view){
    Intent lihatdaftar1 = new Intent(this, DaftarPariwisata.class);
    startActivity(lihatdaftar1);

}

public void lihatPeta(View view){
    Intent lihatpeta = new Intent(this, Maps_Activity.class);
    startActivity(lihatpeta);
}
```

}

**Maps_Activity.java**

```
public class Maps_Activity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not i nstalled on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("bchbbcv"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="6"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.arf_amella.pariwisatacirebon.MainActivity">



<TextView
        android:text="Aplikasi Parawisata"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:text="Lihat Daftar Lokasi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:onClick="lihatDaftar1" />

    <Button
        android:text="Lihat Peta Lokasi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:onClick="lihatPeta" />
    <Button
        android:text="Tambah Lokasi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:text="Keluar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</GridLayout>
```

**maps_activity.xml**

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.arf_amella.pariwisatacirebon.Maps_Activity"
tools:layout="@android:layout/simple_gallery_item" />
```

I can not thank you enough for helping me :)

Comment: you have defined **APK_KEY** multiple times

**The API key can only be specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the element of AndroidManifest.xml**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google maps activity on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780033/google-maps-activity-on-android)

Comment: As @Nishant Pardamwar said, it is stated in the error log that you have defined the API key multiple times. Avoid having `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` meta-data entry. Based from these [thread](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7824) and [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#use-key), `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` is the recommended metadata name for the API key. Meaning, the `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` entry is sufficient for both the Maps and Places services.

Comment: oke work thanks you @chalithageekiyanage.. and thanks all for help me.. :)